# React Native - Search Filter

Tags: javascript, react-native, search

I have this data:

```js
export const recepies = [
{
  key: '1',
  title: 'Recepie Name',
  ingredients: [
    {
      id: '1',
      name: 'pepperoni'
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      name: 'pineapple'
    }
  ]
},
{
  key: '2',
  title: 'Another recepie',
  ingredients: [
    {
      id: '1',
      name: 'apple'
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      name: 'orange'
    }
  ]
}
];
```

I have a filter function that receives a string from a textInput, and then I set the state with the results from that filter.

```js
filter(text) {
    const newData = recepies.filter(function (item) {
      const itemData = item.title.toUpperCase();
      const textData = text.toUpperCase();
      return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1;
    });
    this.setState({
      text: text,
      data: newData,
    });
  }
```

Right now I can only search recepies by their 'title',
how could I search recepies by any of their ingredients

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you're set on writing this out yourself, you'd need to handle filtering at different levels for arrays *containing* keys that match values, cases where keys don't exist, etc.  For a simple implementation, you can modify your function to accept a key, compare using *contains* (.indexOf() > -1) and do a shallow filter as so:

```js
filter(key, text) {
    const newData = recepies.filter((item) =>
      item[key].toUpperCase().indexOf(
        text.toUpperCase()
      ) > -1
    );
    this.setState({
      text: text,
      data: newData,
    });
  }
```

However, I'd **strongly** recommend using `lodash` or even the [searchjs](https://github.com/deitch/searchjs) NPM package that will more gracefully let you search text and handle the normal error and deep-searching cases that you might need.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, I'll try to use lodash, I didn't now about those tools.
Thanks A LOT!

Comment: My pleasure! Can you upvote or accept this answer when you have a moment?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
   filter(text) {
        const newData = recipies.filter((recipe)=>{
          recipe.ingredients.forEach((ingredient)=>{
                 if(ingredient.name === text)
                    return true
           })
        })

   this.setState({
      text: text,
      data: newData,
    });     
}
```